# Elastic Search Query with @ (at sign) bring the same as without

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to match text with an "@" prefix, e.g. "@stackoverflow" on ElasticSearch. I'm using a boolean query, and both these return the exact same results and actually ignore my @ sign:

Query 1 with @:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"default_field":"text","default_operator":"AND","query":"@stackoverflow"}}]}},"size":20}
```

Query 2 without:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"default_field":"text","default_operator":"AND","query":"stackoverflow"}}]}},"size":20}
```

My Mapping:

```
{"posts":{"mappings":{"post":{"properties":{"upvotes":{"type":"long"},"created_time":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},"ratings":{"type":"long"},"link":{"type":"string"},"pic":{"type":"string"},"text":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"}}}}}}
```

I've tried encoding it to \u0040 but that didn't do any difference.

Comment: Can you show your mapping as well?

Comment: @Val added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `text` field is of type text and is analyzed by default by the `standard` analyzer, which means that `@stackoverflow` will be indexed as `stackoverflow` after the analysis process, as can be seen below

```
GET /_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=@stackoverflow
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "stackoverflow",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

You probably want to either use the `keyword` type if you need exact matching or specify a different analyzer, such as `whitespace`, which will preserve the `@` sign in your data:

```
GET /_analyze?analyzer=whitespace&text=@stackoverflow
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "@stackoverflow",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

*UPDATE*:

Then I suggest using a custom analyzer for that field so you can control how the values are indexed. Recreate your index like this and then you should be able to do your searches:

```
PUT posts
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "properties": {
        "upvotes": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "created_time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "ratings": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "link": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "pic": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit confused. You mentioned two options, to change the type to `keyword` or the analyzer. If I do the first option, I'll need to rebuild the index? And if I do the second option, will the queries be slower?

Comment: It all depends on what you need to do with your data. If you only need to do exact matching, then first option is simpler, and yes, it requires reindexing. Second option is not necessarily slower, but it depends on how you want to query your data.

Comment: I want to be able to do boolean queries, like `(@stackoverflow AND #elastic) OR #WhitespaceAnalyzer`. Does this mean 2nd option would be significantly slower?

Comment: Are you going to input the terms exactly as they appear in your document, i.e. with the same lower/upper case and symbols ?

Comment: I'd like the search to be case-insensitive. Symbols like "@" and "#" would be part of the indexed data, and the search query. That was your q, right?

Comment: Is there an easy way to copy the data from the existing index to the new one with the right mapping? Or alter the index?

Comment: Using [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) you can easily copy the data from the old index to the new one.

Comment: Any text or string fields are automatically indexed by elastic? If I have an integer id I'd like to query by for exact match, putting it as long would allow that?

Comment: yes for strings, unless they are declared as `keyword`